# Detect hardware / network adaptor changes

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos, cocoa, networking

Is it possible to detect hardware changes? I'm looking for an update notification that is sent when the network adaptors are changed (i.e. when the user undocks his MacBook).

I already googled, but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used `AFNetworking`, and found it to be the easiest to use for this (listening for adapter changes)

```
#import <AFNetworking/AFNetworkReachabilityManager.h>

- (instancetype)init 
{
   self = [super init];
   if( self )
   {
      [[AFNetworkReachabilityManager sharedManager] startMonitoring];
      [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                            selector:@selector(reachabilityChanged:)
                                                name:AFNetworkingReachabilityDidChangeNotification
                                              object:nil];
   }
   return self;
}


-(void) dealloc
{
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                   name:AFNetworkingReachabilityDidChangeNotification
                                                 object:nil];
}
```

and then implement the handler:

```
- (void)reachabilityChanged:(NSNotification *)notification
{
   NSNumber *s = notification.userInfo[AFNetworkingReachabilityNotificationStatusItem];
   AFNetworkReachabilityStatus status = [s integerValue];

   //Check value of status here
}
```

Here is the header where you can see the constants used for status:
https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/4fb051898c60051d207ca0c24435766fdf140e34/AFNetworking/AFNetworkReachabilityManager.h

I have also used SCReachability

```
   #import <SystemConfiguration/SystemConfiguration.h>

   BOOL networkAvailable = NO;
   const char *hostName = [NEVER_TRANSLATE(@"google.com") cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
   SCNetworkReachabilityFlags flags = 0;
   SCNetworkReachabilityRef target = SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithName(NULL, hostName);

   if (SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags(target, &flags))
   {
      if (flags == kSCNetworkFlagsReachable)
      {
         networkAvailable = YES;
      }
   }
```

Though I used this to detect network availability at a specific time, instead of registering as a listener, so not sure if this will do what you want